# PHPStorm Project Set up from SVN

Tags: svn, phpstorm

I did the following
VCS > Check Out from VCS > Subversion

Added the repository location

myrepopath/mytestproject

The repository has

```
mytestproject
|____ branches
        |___ b1
        |___ b2
|____ tags
|____ trunk
```

After checkout instead of just the code view of trunk, I'm seeing the entire svn repsitory structure with branches directory with all branches and their respective code even, tags directory and trunk directory with code. But in eclipse the moment I checkout top level repo path it auto detects branches and puts the content of trunk alone in workspace and able to switch branches smoothly. Am I missing something out in the setup?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the "trunk" folder, and check this out.

Have fun.